# If $f(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients such that $f(x)\geq f'(x)$ for all $x$, then $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients such that $ f(x)  \ge  f'(x) $ for all $ x \in \mathbb {R}$, show that $ f(x) \ge 0 $ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Hint: Try contradiction. What happens if $f(x)$ is negative for some $x$?

Answer (score 3):

The case $f(x)=c$ is trivial. Let $f(x)$ have positive degree. Now, note that if $f(x)$ has negative leading coefficient, then $f(x)<f'(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ since the degree of $f(x)$ is greater. This is a contradiction, giving us the leading coefficient to be positive and thus, $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$.

Knowing that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, observe that if we ever have $f(x)<0 \implies f'(x)<0$. But then the function would decrease even further. This creates a loop where $f(x)$ can't increase anymore. This would give $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = - \infty$ which is a contradiction.

Thus, $f(x) \geqslant 0$ over reals.

Comment: +1, quite clever